# Structure and size of the ESP and EBP registers

Tags: x86, cpu-architecture, cpu-registers

As I have understood, the stack pointer (ESP) points to the top of the stack. Does it mean that at any time t the ESP contains one single address ? 
Basically, what is the structure of the ESP register ? Same question for the base pointer register (EBP).

It is probably a naive question but I don’t really get a « big picture » of it. Thanks for clearing things up.

Comment: The big picture is it is just as much a regular register as EAX, EBX, and so on. The only real difference is that instructions such as `push` and `pop` change it; nothing else, really.

Answer (score 0):

Each logical core has a single ESP register that contains a single 32-bit value. Note that ESP doesn't necessarily has to be used as a top-of-stack pointer. It's a general purpose register. However, it usually is used as a top-of-stack pointer. In that case, it does only contain a single pointer. In case there are multiple threads, each has its own stack, whenever a thread is scheduled to run on a core, the top-of-stack pointer associated with that thread has to be loaded into the ESP register before the thread is allowed to execute. This overwrites the old value of ESP, which could be the top-of-stack pointer of the previous thread.